# What would prevent my assets from reindexing on a local MAMP install

Tags: assets, reindex, mamp

Having an issue with assets not reindexing from the Update Asset Indexes option.  If I add new folders to the file system they do not appear after I run the Update Asset Indexes, if I upload them manually in the backend then they do appear as normal.

How would I diagnose this?  Running Apache as my logged in user so it's does not seem to be a group / permissions related issue.

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in your browser's console when you run Update Asset Indexes?

Comment: Yup:  POST http://smt.craft.dev/index.php/admin/actions/tools/performAction 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.1.0.min.js?d=1406143654:4
l.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery-2.1.0.min.js ...

Comment: On Craft Client 2.1.2566

Comment: Check your craft/storage/runtime/logs files to see what the underlying error is for the 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Cool... probably worth adding that as the official answer in case someone else runs into it.

Answer (score 1):

If the Update Asset Indexes fails on a MAMP install, double check to make sure ALL assets source paths are correct and exist on the file system.

I had defined a asset source to a folder which I had planned on using but had not yet created on the file system, and this caused the Update Asset Indexes to fail w/o any warning messages, save for a JS error in the console.